# "Один пользователь - одна база данных" - правильно ли, и если нет, то почему?

Tags: база-данных, безопасность, архитектура

Работаю над проектом связанным с аграрным производством. Заказчик очень пристрастен к вопросам безопасности. Одним из пунктов технического задания есть использование для каждого пользователя отдельной базы данных. Аргументация данного подхода состоит в безопасности системы и если злоумышленники взломают одну базу, к остальным добраться не смогут.
Когда я ответил, что с таким подходом к построению структуры базы данных сталкиваюсь впервые и, что возможно, такой подход не практикуется. Однако заказчик ответил, что он уже создавал продукт, который использует данный принцип, один пользователь - одна база данных.

Поэтому есть два вопроса:

1. Насколько данный подход правильный / неправильный и как его возможно реализовать.
2. Если данный подход неправильный, как аргументировать это заказчику?

При этом нужно учитывать что у приложения клиент-серверная архитектура.

Comment: Попробовал дать вопросу более точное название. Пожалуйста отредактируйте, если вам кажется иначе )

Comment: каждый пользователь работает с изолированным набором данных? то есть речь идет о multi-tenancy?

Comment: @Nofate спасибо, теперь узнал данный термин. Да, речь именно о нем. Это как бы веб-приложение для контроля своей работы отдельных предприятий.

Comment: @Kromster спасибо, подойдет)

Comment: Как вариант изолирования доступа - разумный, но весьма затратный (по мне - не окупающий закрытие рисков). Я бы именно так это заказчику и презентовал, вернув ему ответственность по поводу затрат.

Comment: @Etki спасибо, это будет вторым агрументом. Первый - это сложность смены структуры приложения после продакшена.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Подход вполне возможный и в некоторых случаях - логичный. Называется такая архитектура мультитенантной, используется в облачных технологиях чаще всего.

Явные плюсы:

- Sql доступ конкретного клиента можно (я бы даже сказал нужно)
  дополнительно ограничивать sql учеткой.
- Независимость клиентов друг
  от друга.
- Независимость данных клиентов друг от друга.

Что не совсем ясно по вашему вопросу и надо будет учитывать:

- Есть ли общая точка входа для сервисных операций? Она должна быть либо защищена от клиентов, либо клиенты от неё.
- Какая архитектура приложения - клиент-БД или клиент-сервер-БД? В первом случае отдельная база на клиента выглядит обязательной, во втором - в зависимости от нагрузки и требований клиентов.
- Есть ли (нужна ли) у клиентов возможность обновления на разные версии программы? Одна база на всех не даст вам такую возможность.

Можно найти ещё причин, надо смотреть по ситуации.

Comment: спасибо, ситуация проясняется, отвечу по поводу вопросов. 1. Общей точки не будет, так как заказчик сконцентрирован на безопасности, в админке не будет доступа к данным других пользователей. 2. Архитектура клиент-сервер-БД. 3. Вопрос версий думаю актуален всегда, оставлю как аргумент.